# How to present actions from multiple modules on one page in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm rewriting an app to ZF2 and I got stuck on problem of aggregating views from many modules on one page. What I want to achieve is to separate functionalities into modules, but still be able to display their views/actions (not sure how to name it) on one page. Let's say I'd layout a page with 4 containers and each of them would display some view from 4 different modules. Is it possible, if yes then how? Or maybe my though process is wrong here (I'm set on separating those functionalities though).

I've tried defining same or similar routes (eg. Module1: `/boo/[:yah]`, Module2    `/boo/[:whatever]`). It  didn't work because first module loaded was apparently served. And it looks like a mess too.

I've read a little about view helpers, but seemed to be aimed at a different purpose of providing common functionalities across many views. Whereas what I need if something like a layouting helper, view aggregation or something. I've worked with a home-made framework before that had this concept of site controllers, that would fire up different controllers actions. I can't find a way to emulate this in ZF2.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816366/zf2-display-module-action-in-another-module

Comment: Do you just need access to the plain views, or do you want each view rendered  by an action/controller? :)

Comment: I guess the latter. So that `forward controller plugin` is probably something I'm looking for, right? Wonder what happens if I'd need to do that in several actions.

Comment: Read: [Replace the "Action"Helper in ZF2 and create great widgetized Content](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/) by @Bakura10

Comment: @Sam I did and what I took away from it is that I can either create view helpers or forward requests internally to other controllers. Seems quite awkward though, but then I don't really now any better. I'll leave the question open for a while and close it if no other solution comes up.

Comment: I guess the biggest difference is that people say a `ViewHelper` should do simple things. Checking for login status and display a form or the profile > viewhelper. Fetching a couple of products depending on the users profile and past search terms > prolly forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been applying `forward` plugin for this purpose as described in the [blogpost](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/) suggested by Sam. It doesn't *look elegant*, but then I can't think of anything better myself.

Comment: Since I asked this, I've actually grown to like using view helpers most of the time. However I found that I can reuse the controller action for forward request as ajax/esi content, which is actually less confusing and useful on a different level (page responsivness).